# Series of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $\ \rm w_n = 3^{-n}\cos 2n\theta $ for$\ \rm  n = 1, 2, 3,..., $ use de Moivre's Theorem to show that 
$$\ \rm \large \sum^{N-1}_0 w_n = \frac{9-3\cos2\theta+3^{-N+1}\cos2(N-1)\theta-3^{-N+2}\cos2N\theta}{10-6\cos2\theta}$$

**Attempt**
$$\ \rm \large \sum^{N-1}_0 w_n = Re\left[\sum^{N-1}_0 3^{-n}e^{2n\iota\theta} \right]  $$
$$\ \rm \large \sum^{N-1}_0 w_n = Re\left[\frac{1-(\frac{e^{2\iota\theta}}{3})^N }{1-(\frac{e^{2\iota\theta}}{3})} \right]  $$
$$\ \rm \large \sum^{N-1}_0 w_n = Re\left[\frac{1-\frac{e^{2N\iota\theta}}{3^N} }{1-(\frac{e^{2\iota\theta}}{3})} \right]  $$

I am not really sure how to carry on after this. Can somebody provide me some hints which will help me in solving this question?

Comment: Multiply top & bottom by $(1-\frac{e^{-2i \theta}}{3})$.

Comment: Ohhhh perfect thank you very much.

Comment: Can you tell me one thing? Are these equation correct? if $\ z = \frac{x}{y} $ then  $\ Re[z] = \frac{ Re[x]}{Re[y]} $ and $\ Im[z] = \frac{ Im[x]}{Im[y]} $

Comment: And just one another last thing. Is the sum to infinity of the above expression $\ \frac{9-cos2\theta}{10-6cos2\theta} $ or $\ \frac{9-3cos2\theta}{10-6cos2\theta} $ ?

Comment: You cannot do that with real & imaginary part ! ... multiply top & bottom by the conjuagate of the denominator, then the real part will be the real part of the numerator over the (hopefully) purely real denominator.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was wondering the same.

Comment: Sum to infinity ... the latter $9-3 cos 2 \theta$ ...